# Grails Domain Class Not Saving without Groovy.Sql first

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm using Hibernate 3 and Grails 2.2.5.

I have an AJAX call in one of my views that is supposed to look up some data and provide a text result. In the methods used to generate the text result, I have a method call to a service to save the text result to its own domain.

The problem is that the `.save(flush: true)` will not persist to the database. However, if I add a Groovy SQL instance and perform an `.executeInsert()` with any insertion the insert in the Groovy SQL will be inserted AND the `.save(flush: true)` method will work as expected... I've tried various different ways, but as soon as I comment out the `.executeInsert("...")` the domain class will not be persisted.

I've checked common problems: validation checks out (returns true), I turned `deepValidate` to false and I used flush in case Hibernate was trying to save the insertion statement to a later time. I also turned on `logSql = true` in `DataSource.groovy` and the SQL insert statement does get logged when I comment the `.executeInsert("...")` out but is never persisted to the table.

-EDIT/UPDATE-

The Hibernate log has the insert statement as:

```
insert into TextDomain (version, text, ... , id) values (?,?,?,?,?)
```

Are the question marks supposed to be there? Not too experienced with Hibernate so I'm not sure if that's the actual SQL statement it is executing or if it is filling the values in?

Also, the method I'm trying to call `.save()` in is in `src/groovy` .

EDIT/UPDATE -> TEST:

I setup a test as a single action in a controller. I simply called a service method that filled the `textDomain` with some test values and then did a `.save()`. When calling the controller action (i.e. going to the url `my-app:8080/test/text`) the `textDomain` is persisted correctly. However, I tried adding the service that has the actual textDomain instantiation and test values from another service and it will not persist...

Comment: Yes, the question marks are just placeholders for the actual values. Try wrapping the persistence logic in a `withNewSession` closure. The documentation for that is here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/withNewSession.html

Comment: Tried that, still not saving to Database